# carousel trigger when continuous scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, caroufredsel

The carousel (caroufredsel) scroll ([check this for example](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/continuously-scrolling.php)) continously to the left. When I hover to an arrow to the right it will stop scrolling then it will reverse it's direction. I tried using custom events but it appears that it's not working. Here's a code of the carousel.

```
$('#gallery').carouFredSel({
    width: "variable",

    auto: {
        items                   : 4,
        duration                :"40000",
        easing                  :"linear",
        timeoutDuration         :0,
        pauseOnHover        :"immediate"
        },
    items: {
        visible: 3
    }

});
```

Now my custom event that will cause the carousel to reverse is direction is like this. But it's not working until the whole items where finished scrolling. What I want to achieve is to instantaneously reverse the direction when hovering.

```
$('a.prev').hover(function()
{
    $('#gallery').trigger("pause");
    $('#gallery').trigger("configuration",["direction",right]);
    $('#gallery').trigger("play");
}
```

The code above doesn't work and I've tried different events that will simulate the reversal of scrolling but had no luck with it.

If there's no workaround for this. I'm willing to change another plugin that will easily do the work. If you know something that can do it easily please leave your suggestions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends how the carousel is implemented. A possible solution might be to stop the `eventPropagation`. It may or may not work depending on the implementation of the carousel.

```
$('a.prev').hover(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#gallery').trigger("pause");
    $('#gallery').trigger("configuration",["direction",right]);
    $('#gallery').trigger("play");
}
```